# How to include a code snippet in a beamer presentation?

Tags: latex, code-snippets, slide, presentation, beamer

What's the best way to include some code snippets in a beamer presentation?

I've already tried `verbatim`, and `lstlisting` environments - both destroyed my presentation.

Answer (score 26):

Use the `[fragile]` option:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{verbatim}
...
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: I've already tried this, with a strange result. The slide with code looks OK, but all slides before have paper size changed to A4.

Comment: That is *very* strange indeed, as the "paper size" should be 128mm times 96mm to reflect the 4:3 ratio of most beamers output. You didn't fiddle around with that setting, did you?

Answer (score 3):

I recently used something like

```
\verbatiminput{blah.c}
```

in a beamer presentation, and it worked alright for me...

Wanna post your code?